# Start windows application with single core in wine

Tags: wine, games, multi-core

I am trying to run Broken Sword 4 in wine on Ubuntu 14.04. It installed perfectly. However, the usual blackened character problem occurs. This is caused by multicore CPUs. So I have to explicitly enable single core for the game to run flawlessly.

I did so in Windows and enabled single-core and it ran well. Now, how can I do the same in Wine? I already tried taskset and it didn't work.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
Open up play on Linux
```

click on the game you installed then click on configure.
**I am using ImageBurn as an example.**
**Note you need to be running the application.**

[image]

then click on the wine tab
[image]

Then click on Task Manager
[image]
right click the task and click on `go to process`then right click on the process and click on set affinity.

[image]

then unpick the cores you don't want to use.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi, thanks for the solution. But isn't there a way to do this on wine itself?

Comment: @DhirajEadara how did you do it on windows ?

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/66504-processors-limit-number-used-windows-7-a.html

Comment: @DhirajEadara how did you use taskset command ?

Comment: taskset -c 0 wine bs4pc.exe

Comment: Forget it. I cant see the bs4pc option in the task manager in playonlinux

Comment: I am here
`http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30713/discussion-between-neil-and-dhiraj-eadara`